# LibGdx TouchInput gives strange numbers for position on the screen

Tags: android, input, libgdx

have a small problem. Cannot understand how to solve it. 
I am implementing user touch input in my LibGdx game. My screenSize is next: width = 408 and height = 272;
When I am trying to print values I get from method touchDown, I get absolutely weird numbers for positions on the screen. They can be even bigger than 1000... 
How is it even possible if my screenSize is 408x272?

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
System.out.println(screenX + "     " + screenY);    //For some reasons this gives completely absurd numbers for the positions on the screen.
return true;
}
```

It will be very appreciated if you could help me. I think I miss something easy and straightforward... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you screen size is not what you think it is - are you possibly mixing that up with having defined your Camera to view a 408x272 region? Is the size of the window on the screen actually 408x272 pixels?

If this is the issue, you need to do - assuming you are using an `OrthographicCamera`:

```
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
cam.unproject(v3);
```

This will set the `v3.x` and `v3.y` to what you are looking for.

If this is not the issue, I'd try to make sense of how the strange positions are related to the expected ones - does it behave like the screen was larger? Is it flipped? If you manage to observe that, it might be easier to figure out.

Comment: Ohh, Sir thank you for such detailed answer. I will try to make this way!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people will use Vector3 for storing touch points and will use `Gdx.input` to get X and Y coordinates. Checkout [Superjumper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/superjumper/superjumper/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/GameScreen.java) for more details, specifically the `updateRunning` function.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I think I understand now in which direction to move:) Thanks!