# libgdx flip input coordinate system

Tags: android, touch, libgdx, coordinates, flip

I have the Coordinate System for Rendering set to:

```
camera.setToOrtho(false, 288, 512);
```

But the touch-coordinate system is the other one (true, not false)

How can I flip this to read inputs at special positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply flipping isn't the only thing you should do with touch inputs. Inputs are given in pixel coordinates, while your camera uses a 288x512 units system regardless of the display size. Whenever you get touch events, they are given in the current display's pixel coordinates, which is different for different phones and even changes when you resize the screen on desktop. This is the code you need:

```
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
camera.unproject(v3);
```

`screenX` and `screenY` are the touch coordinates given to `InputProcessor` functions or returned by `Input.getX()` and `Input.getY()`.  The 0 is needed because `Camera.unproject()` takes a `Vector3`, it's ignored for an `OrthographicCamera`.

This will set `v3.x` and `v3.y` to the touch coordinates in the camera's coordinate system.

Comment: What is screenX and screenY? And what is the 0?

Comment: screenX and screenY are the touch coordinates you can get either using `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` or, if you're using an `InputProcessor`, the coordinates given in the function calls. (Lack of clarity due to copying from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487195/libgdx-touchinput-gives-strange-numbers-for-position-on-the-screen/22487570#22487570), sorry for that, I'll edit it..) As for the 0, it's needed because `Camera.unproject` takes a `Vector3`, it's ignored for an `OrthographicCamera`.

Comment: Wherever you get your input. Every touch value you collect should go through this.